# error validating report rdl content

Tags: navision

I'm having the above error and I can't figure why.

[image]

I have my var ShowLogo as a global var and initialized

```
OnInitReport()

ShowLogo := TRUE
```

;

Comment: Can’t read the error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't read it either...but I gues it's about using field from the Dataset in the Report Header which is not possible. Have a look at any standard NAV report how the logo has been shown.
The other options is embedding the logo into the report

Cheers!